Problems finding median of an array in c
I am attempting to find the median from an array of data in c, every time I attempt to though, I get zero even though there is only one zero in the array, the array is sorted before being imputed to the function. the array data is valid as I can calculate the average and the sum correctly.
Here is my function:
//The array is sorted prior to this
//count is the amount of values in the array

double median(int64_t *array)
{
        double q2;
        int64_t pos, pos1;
        if (count % 2 == 0) 
        {
                //even
                pos = count / 2;
                pos1 = (count + 2) / 2;
                q2 = (array[pos] + array[pos1]) / 2;
        }
        else
        {
                //odd
                pos = (count + 1) / 2;
                q2 = array[pos];
        }
        return q2;
}


First of all, please [edit] your question to show us a [mre]. What is, for example, count? How is the array initialized? And have you tried to debug your program? For example by using a debugger to step through the code line by line while monitoring variables and their values?

By the way your calculation of the positions for even-numbered count doesn't make sense. Lets say you have 8 elements in the array. You will take the fifth and sixth elements of the array when you should take the fourth (index 3) and fifth (index 4).

Actually, your element calculation for odd-numbered sizes is also wrong. For example for an array of 7 elements, you take the fifth element, instead of the fourth (at index 3).

Oh, and adding two integers and dividing them by 2 will give you an integer result. If you want a double result, divide by 2.0. Furthermore, adding two signed integers could lead to signed integer overflow, which leads to undefined behavior.

Is count a global variable? That's very bad design. The signature of your function should be double median(int64_t *array, int count).

Other than the problems mentioned: The fact you get a result of 0 is a strong indication that the way you print the result is wrong. As you haven't provided a [mcve] nobody can tell for sure. [Edit] and provide one.

You seem to miss that array index starts from zero.
If you have an array with two elements the index to be used is 0 and 1.
However, your calculation is:
// With count equal to 2
pos = count / 2;  ---> 2/2 ---> 1
pos1 = (count + 2) / 2;  ---> (2 + 2)/2 ---> 4/2 ---> 2

So you are using 1 and 2 instead of index 0 and 1.
Try:
pos = (count - 2) / 2;
pos1 = count / 2;

Same problem is present for odd count values.
But do you really need to handle odd and even count values differently?
What about doing
pos = (count - 1) / 2;
pos1 = count / 2;

and then calculate the average of those two array elements.
If we ignore precision for a moment (see later), your function body could be a single line
return (array[(count - 1) / 2] + array[count / 2]) / 2;

However, there are problems with the calculation.
For instance this calculation:
q2 = (array[pos] + array[pos1]) / 2;

is an integer division so you lose the decimal part.
Do
q2 = (array[pos] + array[pos1]) / 2.0;

to get a floating point division.
To get it really correct you should also handle the possibility of integer overflow when doing the addition.
q2 = array[pos] / 2.0 + array[pos1] / 2.0;

That said you should also notice that for large array values you will lose precision when converting from integer to double. If you want this to be correct, you need to return a more "advanced" type than double. That could be a struct.
